# How to access a remote directory and copy files in PHP

Tags: php, file, scandir

I want to copy files from a remote directory. But I don't know how to write its UNC. I can use  file://Server/Production/Images to open the directory in a browser, but it can't work if I just use this path in my PHP script.

```
$origin = "file://Sever/Prodution/Images";
$file = scandir($origin);
```

The rusult is : Warning: scandir(): remote host file access not supported

I have run my wampsever as an administrator, so I assume it can access to remote sever.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.file.php use `\\\` instead.

Comment: The `file://` protocol is not for remote calls!

Comment: I also tried using: 1) \\\Sever\Production\Images 2)\\192.168.34.10\Production\Images  Warning: Access is denied.

Comment: It is a Linux box or windows box? Access is denied mean need correct permission

Comment: May be try `file:///path/to/file.ext`

Comment: The Sever is in Linux, and my desktop is in Window. I tried "///", but it can't work. The warning: The system cannot find the path specified

Answer (score 0):

Without doing any research, I am not sure that 'file://' is a proper protocol to use in a server environment. If you are testing remote file access but are wanting to access files on the local server, you could use `http://localhost/path/to/file` or `http://127.0.0.1/path/to/file`. You will also need to make sure that the file is with a 'web accessible' directory on your machine. For example, if your wamp stack's webroot is C:\programs\wamp\apache\html\ and the file you are trying to access is located in C:\Sever\Prodution\Images then the file will not be accessible. Make Sense?

Comment: The files are not stored in my computer, but a remote server. I want to copy some files from a folder there. I can see the folder from a browser with "//Sever/..." , but can't access to it with my PHP script.

Comment: To access those files with php you will need to use either the ip address of the remote host or its domain. Something like `remoteserver.com/Sever/Prodution/Images` or `123.234.345.456//Sever/Prodution/Images`. If your browser is accessing the files using only '//Sever/Prodution/Images' with no domain or ip and the files are not on your local machine, then your browser must be setup to access a remote drive via a plugin or something. In that case, php won't be able to access the same files because php doesn't have the access to the remote drive that your browser does.