# Show thumbnail from local file in browser (using free technology)

Tags: browser, local-storage, file-access

I'm developing a database in Postgresql, accessed via browser (php/javascript) in Firefox/Ubuntu. It runs locally in the client machine, with database also local. Some tables have a "link" column, where the user stores the path to the file for that record (a report, a photo, a map, or even a whole folder). Right now I'm asking the client to copy the resource in Nautilus and paste it in the field of choice. This pastes the full path of the file, which is then stored in the database. So far, so good.

What I want now is to show a thumbnail of the files when the user asks to see what is on that table. I know javascript can't have access to the user disk's contents for security reasons. [This site](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) shows how to do something similar in HTML5, but it doesn't seem to have the full path for the file. Somewhere else I've read Flash could do it (somewhere else I read it couldn't), but Flash is not free. Any free technology to make this work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm trying in Java, it displays the image nicely in the applet-tester, but not in the browser (it displays the "Hello, world!" in the browser, though)  :(  Will I need to do a Windows-Delphi database or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways of going about this. One option would be for the server to stream the images from the path in the database to the browser, for example if using PHP this would look like:

```
    $size = getimagesize($fname);
    // Now that you know the mime type, include it in the header.
    header('Content-type: '.$size['mime']);
    // Read the image and send it directly to the output.
    readfile($fname);
```

There are equivalent methods in any other server side scripting language.

Specifically, here's a tested sample code that does this. On the server side:

```
<?php
$param = $_GET["image"];
$fname = "/Users/myuser/images/$param"; // replace with your path
$size = getimagesize($fname);
header('Content-type: '.$size['mime']);
readfile($fname);
?>
```

On the client side

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<img src="http://127.0.0.1/img.php?image=test1.png" />
<img src="http://127.0.0.1/img.php?image=test2.png" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok, testing it. If $fname = "/home/user/folder/file.png" and I have this file in that directory. If I do: $size = getimagesize("file:/$fname"); I'm getting "remote host file access not supported" Looks like my folder /home/user/folder/ will need to be "web accessible" like stated here http://stackoverflow.com/a/19013167/1086511 ?

Comment: If you are doing this in PHP and PHP runs in the same server where the files are located then $fname should be the absolute path of the file (without the 'file:/' prefix). For example if the file is /home/myuser/images/myimage.jpg then you should use $size = getimagesize('/home/myuser/images/myimage.jpg') and readfile('/home/myuser/images/myimage.jpg')

Comment: Ok, it can open the image. But the header means I need a new page to open it. What I'd like to do is have several images open in the same page, where I have other elements (a lateral bar with a menu, a table in the main div, etc). The images should be thumbnails in the main screen. But the main screen has a header that is not of the mime file type of the image.

Comment: I tried with a link <a href='showIMG.php?file=$fname&mime=$mime' target='_blank'>, it opens a new page but gives an error: "The image <image> cannot be displayed because it contains errors." In <image> it is showing the full url, but I called readfile() passing only the name of the file, as you said. Why is this?

Comment: headers are always sent back with images - you don't need a new page to display them - simply use <img src="showIMG.php?file=$fname" />. If you managed to view the image this way in a new page, you should be able to see multiple images in the same page using the img tag

Comment: It's not showing the image, only a icon of a broken image link... :(

Comment: And no, I didn't managed to view the image this way in a new page. It gave that error message.

Comment: See the additions to my original replay. I've tested it and it works (i.e displays the two images in the same page)

Comment: So it must be something in my configuration...? It's displaying only the broken image icon, and if I copy the location of the image icon (http://servername/showIMG.php?file=/home/user/folder/file.png) to a new tab, it displays that annoying error message: The image "http://servername/showIMG.php?file=/home/user/folder/file.png" cannot be displayed because it contains errors. Trying with different images, png, jpg, all the same.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49584/discussion-between-rodrigo-and-amnon)